# What are some cloud services to host a JanusGraph which uses ScyllaDB+ES for backend?

Tags: graph-databases, gremlin, janusgraph, gremlin-server, scylla

I have explored compose for JanusGraph which is supported by [BlueMix](http://console.bluemix.net) and [Compose.com](https://www.compose.com/)

but they both offer services for 0.1.1 version. So I cannot use them both. Is there any other option that I have?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, Compose is the only hosted JanusGraph service. Is there a particular feature in JanusGraph 0.2.0 that you require?

Comment: It has latest ElasticSearch support

Comment: thanks, makes sense

Answer (score 0):

[IBM Cloud](https://www.ibm.com/cloud/compose/janusgraph), through [Compose](https://compose.com/), is currently the only cloud provider with a managed JanusGraph offering and it's been this way for quite a while now. On the JanusGraph GitHub [repo](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph), they state who provides managed hosting at the bottom. I believe should and when other providers join the bandwagon, they would reach out to update that part of the READ.ME as a matter of priority, so you can always monitor there for any changes.

That said, I understand the developer urge to always use the latest and greatest versions of software, but if you really want to go the managed solutions way, this is one area that you'll have to compromise on in exchange for stability and reliability.